# Trouble with making a DC-DC converter

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, esp32

I have been trying to make this DC-DC converter:

[image]

I used a J380 p-channel MOSFET instead of the IRF9640 and a EK-04 schottky diode instead of the MBRS360 in the real circuit. In addition, I used a AIRD-03-391K as an inductor because it can handle currents of more than 4 Amps. I did not have a proper load, so I just used two 10 ohm resistors (I know they will get hot). My PWM source was an ESP32(5kHz, 50% duty cycle). Oscilloscope showed no problems with the signal.

I tried doing some tests with the circuit. When I applied 10 V to the input the output voltage was either 0 V or starting to rise very slowly from around 200 mV. Sometimes the output current went up to 200mA and then quickly dropped down to 0A but for others it stayed at 0A. I thought I had damaged the J380(because I switched the source with the gate by accident), so I replaced it with a new one but got the same results. Replacing the inductor with an axial one did not help as well.

Could anyone tell me what might be issue with the circuit? Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

It seems that part of the problem was the breadboard (or my brain) and that is why I got 0V at the output. When I switched breadboards everything was working fine (5.32V at the output) apart from the load resistors getting really hot. I tried to connect them in parallel and switching the frequency to 20 kHz (see the answer below) but neither of those things solved the issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Circuit and breadboard look alright (well, placement and lead length could be a lot better, but you aren't driving it very fast, and it should do well enough as-is). What does the scope say at other points in the circuit?

Comment: Actually, I did not do any further testing with the scope. I will make sure to do it next time I am at the lab.

Comment: (A *regulator* is something with a (negative) feedback loop. This is just a *step-down* /  *buck "converter "*.)

Comment: "*When I switched breadboards everything was working fine apart from the load resistors smoking again*" -- What do you mean "again"? You say output voltage was zero, therefore heat should be zero as well. It sounds like you addressed the output voltage problem then. But you don't say the problem has been solved. Which is it? Are you measuring incorrectly (e.g. DMM set to AC range)? What does the oscilloscope say?

Comment: @TimWilliams I used three different breadboards in total. When I had the 1st one my axial inductor and resistors were getting super hot. Then, I bought a better inductor and switched the board to the 2nd one. However, the output voltage went to 0V and that is why I made the post. I was just trying to say that with the 3rd board I am getting an output voltage now (5.32V). I am sorry for the confusing EDIT.

Comment: @TimWilliams Would using cement resistors instead of the 2x10 ohm regular resistor load be a bad idea? I tried to use a 5W 2 ohm cement resistor but the output current reached 1A by the time the input voltage got to 5 V and then the power supply just stopped.

Comment: Resistor *type* doesn't matter at DC, as long as they're not overloaded or anything. It sounds like the *value* wasn't appropriate. This question seems to be done but you might ask a new question if you have further concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My PWM source was an ESP32(5kHz, 50% duty cycle)

> When I applied 10 V to the input

You may want the operation to be CCM (continuous conduction mode) as you run the circuit open-loop i.e. no feedback to stabilise the output voltage.

For CCM, output will be half the input voltage (50% duty-cycle, 10/2 =  5V for your initial tests). For 5 kHz (100 us for both on- and off-time) which is really low to me, the inductor current swing will be 1.3 Amps (this may not be a problem as the inductor you chose can handle 4 Amps). To maintain CCM, the output load current should be at least half the swing, making 0.7 Amps. For 5V output voltage, you'll need a load resistance of 7 Ohms at max.

From the setup I can see that you have 20 Ohms of load resistance forcing the operation point to be DCM. In DCM the output voltage becomes load-dependent. This is probably why you get unstable output voltage.

Either decrease the load resistance to somewhere below 7 Ohms (parallel those two 10 Ohms, for example) or increase the frequency (e.g. 20 kHz or higher).

Comment: My plan is to add a some additional sensors and make this a 9V Li-ion battery charger (the battery will become the load). I do not have the battery yet, so I am just randomly using a 20 ohm load which I now know is a bad idea. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @kauselis3000 Please don't try to charge a Li-Ion Battery directly on this. If you only plan to power an external circuit containing the Li-Ion battery, ignore this comment. In addition to voltage, Li-Ion Batteries need to be current controlled (you can possibly get away with making sure your charging circuit can not generate more current than the battery takes, but then your voltage will drop) in order to not become a fire hazard or wear out quickly. Also, overshooting on the voltage can cause fire, too.

Comment: In addition, your MOSFET has a parasitic body diode, which will allow reverse current flow from the battery into your power supply, which you likely want to safeguard against. If your battery does not come with a protection circuit (some 16850 type batteries do), you will also want to add undervoltage lockout to prevent damage. Draining Li-Ion too far is damaging, too.

Comment: @CharlieBrown I am planning to use a INA219 and ESP32 to measure and control the supplied current.  My end goal is to have a small 2 wheel robot that can be charged using a 20V solar panel. It just has to work and that is it (no long-term use expected).

Comment: @kauselis3000 `to measure and control the supplied current` how will you control the supplied current?

Comment: @CharlieBrown I guess I might have to use a different battery (maybe Ni-MH) due to the lack of my knowledge regarding safe Li-ion battery charging. I have yet to decide what kind of a DC motor I will use.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have read that you can use ESP32 for PID control.

Comment: @kauselis3000 you can use even a shovel as long as you meet the dynamic behaviour requirements :) So your regulator will operate as CV/CC *(constant voltage / constant current)*? Don't misunderstand, I'm asking this because the scope of your question topic has now got a new direction. If your aim is to charge a battery, regardless of the chemistry, the regulator should be able to operate either CC or CV depending on the charging process. If you plan to adjust the current with the PWM mentioned in your question then that'll be the wrong way. Just saying.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The inspiration for my project was this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oFlc4jv2-g . As far as I understand, CC is being used to charge a NiMH battery in the video. I can't explain it well, so I think it is best for you to watch the video.

Comment: @kauselis3000 now it makes sense. Requires serious attention. Good luck with your project.