# Troubles with a 20 V solar panel and a DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, esp32

This is part 2 of my previous post. ([Trouble with making a DC-DC converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686643/trouble-with-making-a-dc-dc-converter))

Since my previous post, I have finished making my DC-DC converter (switched my power supply and added two 5 W 2 Ω cement resistors in series for the load). I have also installed a INA219 sensor to measure the load voltage and current. [image]

The circuit worked fine with my TEXIO 18V-5A DC POWER SUPPLY. However, I started to have issues when I switched to a 20 V solar panel. At 1:30 PM (November 16th Japan, sunny day) the output voltage of the panel was ~19.2 V and the current ~0.12 A. I connected this panel to my DC-DC voltage converter (ESP32 was running PWM at 5 kHz 80% duty connected to my laptop) and INA219 measured ~0.7 V and ~0.12 A at the load. I was really surprised by these results. With the same PWM conditions and input voltage I got way bigger values when I used my power supply.

I do not have a datasheet for this solar panel but I know that it is around 15 years old. At the back of the panel someone wrote that it's 12 V/500 mA which is confusing. [image: 20V(?) solar panel]

I am concerned since I eventually want to a charge a lithium-ion battery with this system(along with some sort of overcharge protection IC), so I need to have a stable current and voltage at the output.

Why is the voltage so small and the current practically the same at the load when I use my solar panel? How should I go about this problem? What should I do to increase the output current and voltage?

EDIT:
Schematic of the DC-DC converter without the INA219

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW33o.png]

Comment: Most DC-DC converters without MPPT will struggle, loose regulation and almost short out your panel when you come close to consuming the available power. Have you considered an MPPT capable DC-DC?

Comment: @winny I believe I do not have the skills nor the time to make a MPPT converter by this point. I am just doing this for a school project and I only have around 2 months left. I got my inspiration from this video and figured that everything will be fine if I use an ESP32: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oFlc4jv2-g

Comment: Please post a schematic. You can implement an MPPT or a more crude MPPC in software if you want.

Comment: @winny I have posted the schematic in my previous post which I linked but I will make sure to post it here too. I have explained it in more detail in that post.

Comment: Thanks. Can you measure V1 from your ESP32? If yes, you can implement MPPC. You need two loops, one outer to keep Vin >0.8 of Voc and an inner one to keep output voltage to your setpoint.

Comment: I will make sure to do that tomorrow when I am back at the lab. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You are most welcome. Also, please try to minimize the switch loop area as much as possible. Breadboard is not ideal, you want a PCB with ground plane. 5 kHz is also very low. Have you calculated your inductance and peak current rating for it?

Comment: Does this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689083/331962 tell you what you need to know about panel behaviour?  (Your load exceeds the available panel power, so the output voltage collapses.)

Comment: What is the voltage measured at the solar panel when you have DC/DC converter and load connected? It is set by the input impedance of your DC/DC converter. Maybe [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531556/solar-panel-voltage-drops-when-connected-to-load/531561#531561) is also helpful.

Comment: @ocrdu I will make sure to check it. Thanks.

Comment: @winny I am not sure what peak current for an inductance means. The peak current for the inductor is over 5 A. I have decided to solder every component onto a regular board(I have never worked with a PCB).

Comment: @colintd Yes, I think it does.

Comment: Grand.  In that case I will suggest this question is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: This question also have a good explanation of the problem. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/531561/331962

Comment: At low frequency and for a given output current, you will see higher peak currents. What's the saturation current of your inductor? Or is it an air core?

Comment: @winny Inductor is AIRD-03-391K and the saturation current for it is 6.7 A

Comment: Good, and what's you calculated or simulated peak current?

Comment: LTspice shows that the peak current flowing through the inductor is 2.5 A

Comment: @winny I can actually use a voltage divider along with the ESP32 to measure voltages that are 3 V and above. How can I make this crude MPPT with software (Arduino IDE)? Could you please share any sources of how this could be done?

Comment: Sorry, not really. But a google search revealed many examples. Your standard MPPT application is battery charging whereas yours is slightly different. If I would start from scratch (I'm only a hobby programmer), I would have a loop to check the input voltage every 10 ms or so and if below 0.8*Voc of your panel, bump down the duty cycle by one tick. You need to make sure that the global regulation of input voltage will win over your inner loop to keep the output voltage (which will try to increase the duty cycle). Perhaps a nested loop where output regulation will request a duty cycle...

Comment: ... and passed on to your global which if Vin>0.8Voc will pass it on to your PWM output but if Vin<0.8Voc will scale it back by some factor.

Comment: Winnie's suggestion about keeping the panel voltage up is good. Start the pwm at low duty cycle and monitor v panel. Slowly increase duty cycle until the panel voltage reaches about 0.8 of Voc. Do not let vpanel fall. below this level